# Why does Unity crash when I move a sprite horizontally?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I just started Unity and I was making a 2D game of a player (sprite) that shoots an arrow when I click a specific button. The player moves vertically and the arrow moves horizontally. The player moves fine but, when I click to shoot the arrow, Unity crashes and I have to close it from Task Manager.

The code shows 0 errors and everything else works fine except for Unity.

I don't know where the problem is so, I'll show the whole code; the function that shoots the arrows is called `shootingsysytem`.

```
void Start()
{
    health = 100;
    playerspeed = 2;
    shotspeed = 3;
    bulletcount = 3;
    playerpos();
    if (delay <= 0)
    {
        delay = 0;
    }
    stopbullets();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    playermouvement();
    shootingsystem();
    playerpos();
    delay -= Time.deltaTime;
}

public void playermouvement()// works
{
    if (Input.GetKey("z"))
    {
        player[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Time.deltaTime * playerspeed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        player[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.down * Time.deltaTime * playerspeed);
    }
}// works

public void shootingsystem() // this function shoots the arrows.........
{
    if (Input.GetKey("k"))
    {
        if (bulletcount == 3 & delay <= 0.0f)
        {
            bullet3shot = true;
            while (bullet3shot)
            {
                player[3].transform.Translate(Vector2.left * Time.deltaTime * shotspeed);
            }
            if (delay <= 0.0f)
            {
                bulletcount--;
                delay = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (bulletcount == 2 & delay <= 0.0f)
        {
            bullet2shot = true;
            while (bullet2shot)
            {
                player[2].transform.position += goingside * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (delay <= 0.0f)
            {
                bulletcount--;
                delay = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (bulletcount == 1 & delay <= 0.0f)
        {
            bullet1shot = true;
            while (bullet1shot)
            {
                player[1].transform.Translate(Vector2.left * Time.deltaTime * shotspeed);
            }
            if (delay <= 0.0f)
            {
                bulletcount--;
                bulletcount = 3; // remove later 
                delay = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void playerpos()//works
{
    playerposition = player[0].transform.position;
    if (!bullet1shot)
    {
        player[1].transform.position = playerposition;
    }
    if (!bullet2shot)
    {
        player[2].transform.position = playerposition;
    }
    if (!bullet3shot)
    {
        player[3].transform.position = playerposition;
    }
}//works

private void stopbullets()
{
    if (player[1].transform.position.x <= -13) //stop first bullet
    {
        bullet1shot = false;
    }
    if (player[2].transform.position.x <= -13) //stop second bullet
    {
        bullet2shot = false;
    }
    if (player[3].transform.position.x <= -13) //stop third bullet
    {
        bullet3shot = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have an infinite loop.

```
            bullet1shot = true;
            while (bullet1shot)
            {
                player[1].transform.Translate(Vector2.left * Time.deltaTime * shotspeed);
            }
```

Comment: i used the stopbullets() function to stop that loop.maybe i understand c# wrong how can i fix it ??

Comment: @kuruttakao no, you have an infinte loop, You  set a var to true, you enter the loop and run the loop until bulletshot1 becomes false. You loop once, you do something with player.transform. you loop twice, you  do the same you loop until infinity and you do the same. bullet1shot never gets changed inside this loop - so the loop will never close and continue, because its always true.

Comment: So remove the infinite loop.

Comment: @kuruttakao figured it out?

Comment: yeah! thx for the help . i moved the 'bullet1shot = true;' to another location then removed the while function